# How to auto sync a updated data from database in php, like a online multiplayer game or facebook or instagram post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make a multiplayer web game using a php, MySQL and javascript. But i haven't solution of auto fetching (sync) updated data at a time from the database.

What I want do like:
Ex. Automatic fetch a updated data from database When I post any photo on my account and show the my photo at time on my followers device without refresh the page.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $.ajex({
    url: "fetch.php",
    data: {
      //Something data
    },
    success: function() {
      //Fetch a data in every 1s.
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

But it get a delay of fetching data and make a load on page.
If data is updated on database table than fetch data otherwise not.
I want to other method to auto fetching a updated data.

Comment: AJAX is not the right solution to those requirements. What you're describing would be best solved using the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), as such research WebSockets

Comment: As well as websockets, you could potentially look at server sent events SSE if you only need to receive info from the server https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events.